# Can all Wifi emitters dynamically select frequencies? Or is specific hardware support needed?

Tags: wifi

Using the linux kernel and a wifi adapter I was able to emit a signal and read it from other devices, however my software only allows to transmit over a preset channel of the 2.4GHZ frequency. Most routers change frequencies dynamically based on the amount of interference present, this is called [Dynamic Frequency Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_selection).

Since most of the neighbouring routers use Dynamic Frequency Selection, I'm forced to implement it, however I need to know whether dfs requires any type of hardware support that might not be present in my adapter. Am I safe to rule out hardware limitation and freely attribute my issue to missing software support?

Answer (score 1):

DFS (Dynamic Frequency Selection) is not only a part of the hardware (well, firmware), it’s required, especially if certain 5GHz channels are used. If your router is dual-band it has DFS.

Note that DFS is only intended to avoid interfering with non-WiFi users of the 5GHz band, like Doppler radar. It’s a very limited agility mechanism specific to avoiding these other users. It’s very slow when it kicks in; basically the AP shuts down, switches to a new channel, and starts back up. It takes many seconds to complete.

DFS is *not* intended to avoid other Wi-Fi users; they’re supposed to coexist and share the channel.

At startup, an access point can (and does), scan for a quiet channel and select one. Or you can override this and manually select a channel by managing the AP. But this is a static selection; the link establishment overhead for 802.11 is fairly high so it’s not feasible for it be agile in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Your router uses frequency hopping to communicate to devices even if interference is present. Your router normally operated at 2.5GHz unless dual-band. In the frequency of 2.5GHz, there are small divisions namely channels. Your router hopps to different channels to prevent interference. The frequency of 2.5GHz is approximately set using some particular frequency local oscillator(I guess). Some fine-tuning is done through software to allow change of channels. Software Defined Radio(SDR) can sweep across a wide frequency range. Your router is able to change the frequency but by a very small amount. Since the length of the antenna is also dependent on frequency, if you change the frequency too much, the gain will be reduced drastically. So there is both hardware and software limitation to changing frequency. Hardware blocks you to change frequency beyond limit and software allows only a certain narrow frequency band.

Comment: 802.11 (except -FH) does not 'frequency hop' in the sense that you mean (e.g., switching frequencies in real-time like Bluetooth or 802.11-FH) to avoid interfering with other devices. Rather, APs that share the same channel will coexist with each other. They do this using a mechanism called Carrier Sense / Multple Access / Collision Avoidance, CSMA/CA. More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance